# DevMode, Videomodedescriptor: Screen Refresh Rate Data

Tags: display, refresh-rate

The `dmDisplayFrequency` in [DEVMODE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodew) appears to be the vertical {[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate)} refresh rate for a monitor- does that necessarily correspond to the `VerticalRefreshRateNumerator`/`VerticalRefreshRateDenominator` in [videomodedescriptor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/videomodedescriptor) rounded to the nearest integer?

Else, wrt to monitors of recent manufacture, would `HorizontalRefreshRate(Numerator,Denominator)` ever play a key role in the formulation of `dmDisplayFrequency`?

Comment: @Anton: Suggest anywhere else for it on Stack Exchange?

Comment: please, add the relevant tags and edit the question to fit this community better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the vertical refresh rates correspond but rounding is required, as `dmDisplayFrequency` values are read off as unsigned integers. The following AHK script shows the rounded values:

```
Enabled := ComObjError(1)
wmi := ComObjGet("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" A_ComputerName "\root\wmi")

for monitor in wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT NumOfMonitorSourceModes, MonitorSourceModes FROM WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes WHERE Active=TRUE",,wbemFlagForwardOnly := 32)
{
Loop, % monitor.NumOfMonitorSourceModes - 1
modes .= "`n" . monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].HorizontalActivePixels . " " . monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].VerticalActivePixels . " Horz refresh: " . Round(monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].HorizontalRefreshRateNumerator/monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].HorizontalRefreshRateDenominator) . " Vert refresh: " . Round(monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].VerticalRefreshRateNumerator/monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].VerticalRefreshRateDenominator)
msgbox % monitor.InstanceName . "`n" . modes
}
```

Repeated sets of values are attributed to interlacing or perhaps even panning.
For the older monitors and TV attached in this setup the horizontal rates are much larger, would they have special meaning? In one or two cases here the numerator and corresponding denominator are much larger again, but again produce a result to the order of 10<sup>5</sup>.